# Question about Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces

Tags: c, operating-system

At chapter 14, there are some cases of abuse memory.
This paragraph is one of them,
but I couldn't understand the example.

**Freeing Memory Before You Are Done With It**
Sometimes a program will free memory before it is finished using it; such
a mistake is called a dangling pointer, and it, as you can guess, is also a
bad thing. The subsequent use can crash the program, or overwrite valid
memory (e.g., you called free(), but then called malloc() again to
allocate something else, which then recycles the errantly-freed memory).

I couldn't understand the sentence, "you called free(), but then called malloc() again to
allocate something else, which then recycles the errantly-freed memory".

It seems no problem if the user free memory, then reallocate.
I think the code that the example explains would be like this:

```
int* p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
free(p);
p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Could you explain why this code would be problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example is not correct one, it is better to think of it as:

```
int* p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
free(p1);

char* p2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
// p2 happens to be the same as p1, because deallocated memory is reused

...
*p1 = 12;
...
*p2 = 34;
```

in this case you have dangling pointer `p1` which is still used by some parts of code while others use the same memory for different purpose